# how to know how many elements are currently in a BlockingQueue using Java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have a Java application and I am using Spring Framework.

Using beans I define a queue with its size set to a maximum of 5 elements like below:

```
  <bean id="Queue1" class="java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue">
      <constructor-arg type="int"><value>5</value></constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

Then I pass it to the constructor in Java using injection and I initialize it within the constructor. In Java I have defined and done below:

```
private final BlockingQueue<OrdenTrabajo> queue;
...
this.queue = queue
...
```

Later, when I try to get queue size in code using:

```
queue.size()
```

it returns 0 instead of 5. Why?

Also, is there any possibility to obtain the number of elements that are currently in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int constructor parameter is an [*initial capacity*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue(int)), not the number of elements present initially.

[`PriorityBlockingQueue.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#size()) returns the number of elements present in the collection; [`PriorityBlockingQueue.remainingCapacity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity()) returns the available capacity.

Comment: While `size()` returns the number of items in the queue, not the capacity of the queue.

Comment: ok, so I understand that to know how many items there are in the queue I can use size(). Regarding capacity, I want to limit the queue to only 5 items so it is correct as I do through the bean by setting the int parameter to 5? and I would like to check from code that capacity is actually 5, is there any function that returns it? thx.

Comment: @AndyTurner By doing queue.remainingCapacity it returns 2147483647 instead of 5..... Why

Comment: Very sorry. I read the documentation and I notice that PriorityBlockingQueue always returns this value due to its contraint. Thx.